# Ensuring a variable has a particular type in an interface: python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

```
class A(object)
class B(object)
    self.a = A
class C(B):
    self.a = D
```

I want to make sure D is always a subclass of A. Is that doable in Python w/o using type hints?

Comment: type-hints wouldn't do that. You have to check the `type` of objects at runtime yourself.

Comment: i meant is there a way to _enforce_ that contract?

Comment: You have to check the types yourself at runtime using `type` or `isinstance`. Python doesn't have static type checking out of the box, you'd have to use type-hints and then a third-party static-type checker like `mypy`.